# Passing parameters to Web.config transformation in MsBuild script

Tags: msbuild, web-config

I have transformation file:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <runtime>
        <asm:assemblyBinding xmlns:asm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <asm:dependentAssembly xdt:Locator="Condition(asm:assemblyIdentity/@name='Company.Product')">
                <asm:codeBase xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(version,href)" version="1.2.3.4" href="FILE://D:/Path/To/Company.Product.dll" />
                <asm:bindingRedirect xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(newVersion)" newVersion="1.2.3.4" />
            </asm:dependentAssembly>            
        </asm:assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

It is possible run task **TransformXml** (or something similar) with *version* as parameter?

My buildscript must recognize version of some assembly and set this version as attribute in web.config file.

Comment: Are you building your web.config as part of an MSBuild task for every build?  Are you building the assembly from which you're deriving the version information?

Comment: Every build my website must be deployed on server. Assembly is located on server and sometimes updates. Buildscript must recognize assembly version and write it to web.config.